# Confusion regarding fork() system call in C

Tags: c, fork

I dont understand what is the difference between `fork() & fork()` and `fork() && fork()`. I also get different output for both of them.

```
fork() & fork();
printf("hi\n");

Output : hi
hi
hi
hi
```

---

```
fork() && fork();
printf("hi\n");

Output: hi
hi
hi
```

Can anyone please explain whats going on here. Is this an issue regarding compiler? (I am using gcc on ubuntu14)

Comment: The way I would approach this problem is to first learn the difference between `&` and `&&` by finding a resource about C operators.  Then I would learn what `fork` does by reading the POSIX specification for it or the Linux man page for it.

Answer (score 3):

One is doing a logical test, the other is doing a bitwise and of the result.

```
 fork() && fork()
```

This will fork.  In the parent, it will fork again because the first fork evaluates to a non-zero value (the pid) while in the child it will not.

```
 fork() & fork()
```

Both the parent and children will fork because this performs a bitwise and of the return value of the fork (either a PID or a zero).

Answer (score 1):

in `fork() && fork()` the first fork return 0. This means false and so the evaluation of the rest of the `&&` clause is abandoned (it will be false regardless of the value of the rest of the clause)

The `&` version always evaluates (executes) both sides

Its like

```
 if (x != null && x->foo == 42)
    printf("42");
```

the second part (foo==42) is not touched if the first part (x!= null) is false

Answer (score 1):

This is due to the `&&` operator's [short-circuit evaluation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Short-circuit_evaluation) property. Basically, for any expression `x && y`, `x` is first evaluated. If the result is `false`, `y` is not evaluated at all and the whole expression evaluates into `false`. Otherwise, the result is that of evaluation `y`, casted as a boolean if necessary. So, for instance, `false && printf( "Is this evaluated?\n" )` won't print anything.

This means that `fork() && fork()` will first evaluate the first `fork()`, and evaluate the second one if and only if the first one results in a non-zero result. In the particular case of the `fork()` function, this only happens in the parent process, since the child gets a `0` return status. Thus, the original parent forks twice, but the childs do not. The result is that only three processes will be spawned.

The `&` operator, on the other hand, has no short-circuit evaluation, since it's not a logical-AND, but a bitwise-AND. Since `&` is not about boolean values, but about bits (unlike `&&`), both arguments are always evaluated. This means that in the case of `fork() & fork()` the parent will fork twice, and the first child will fork again, resulting in four different processes.

BTW, you should be learning the C language rather than jumping straight to `fork()`. If you use a tool you don't understand issues like this will come back to haunt you quite often.